# How can i compare the single string with multiple string in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

here is my sample data

```
Doc1     Doc2
US1A     US1U | US1F | US1G
US1B     US1O | US1T
US1C     US1A | US1O | US1N | US1P | US1M
US1D     US1B | US1O | US1N | US1P | US1M | US1E
```

i would like to use the Doc1 compare the string to Doc2
if string in column Doc1 is found in Doc2, it will add to the new data frame with the row that has a string in Doc1 and the compared string.

for example, in Doc1, US1A is found in row US1C from Doc2.

```
new_df.append(df_doc1[j],df_doc1[i])
```

then it will add to the new data frame and expected result will be

```
new_Doc1  new_Doc2
US1A      US1C
US1B      US1D
```

referred to the expected result, here is my code

```
df_doc1 = df[['Doc1']]
df_doc2 = df[['Doc2']]

for i in range(1, len(df)):
    for j in range(1, len(df)):
        aa = df_doc1.isin(df_doc2)
        new_df = pd.DataFrame()
        if np.all(aa!=0):
            if bb==1:
                new_df.append(df_doc1[j],df_doc1[i])
            if bb>1:
                new_df.append(df_doc1[j])
                new_df.append(df_doc1[j])
        bb=bb+1

new_df
```

but the problem is my code return nothing when I print new_df, any suggestion? and thank you in advance

Comment: while appending just do new_df = new_df.append(df_doc1[j], df_doc1[i])

Comment: thank you for your comment, but i still got nothing in the new data frame ._.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
s = df.set_index('Doc1').Doc2.str.split(' \| ').explode()
new_df = s[s.isin(s.index)].reset_index().add_prefix('new_')

Out[28]:
  new_Doc1 new_Doc2
0     US1C     US1A
1     US1D     US1B
```

If you want column labels and order exact as your expected output, you may change it a little bit as follows

```
new_df = (s[s.isin(s.index)].rename_axis('new_Doc2')
                            .reset_index(name='new_Doc1').sort_index(1))

Out[40]:
  new_Doc1 new_Doc2
0     US1A     US1C
1     US1B     US1D
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, i understand for split '|' and could you explain the \ please? moreover, i have tried to solve the attribute explode() error. do you have any suggestion for this issue?

Comment: @Sujin try updating pandas version to `0.25+`

Comment: @Sujin: I split on regex pattern  `' | '` which is string of 3 chars `space`, `|`, `space`. In regex, `|` is special char to indicate alternation (meaning `or` in regex). To turn special  `|` back the literal `|`, it is required \ in front of it. On `explode` , as @anky_91 said, you should update to `pandas 0.25+` to have `explode` available.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `get_dummies` and then getting max of each group with reindex and idxmax like below:

```
m = df['Doc2'].str.get_dummies().set_index(df['Doc1'])
m.columns = m.columns.str.strip()
m.groupby(m.columns,axis=1).max().reindex(columns=m.index).idxmax().reset_index(name='Doc2')
```

---

```
   Doc1  Doc2
0  US1A  US1C
1  US1B  US1D
2  US1C   NaN
3  US1D   NaN
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, there is some missing data that should be shown in the result. for example,   
Doc1  Doc2
0  US1A  US1C
1  US1B  US1D
2  US1C   NaN
3  US1D   NaN
4 US1E    US1A
but it's show only the first data. is it because of the idxmax()?

Comment: @Sujin yes. for multiple matches, how do you want your output like , i guess Andy's method is better here